# Wordpress Advanced Custom Field - Include Tracking Number in order page

Tags: wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I use ACF to send the tracking number to my customers . I created a field where I manualy add a tracking number and it send a message to the customer on the order completion email. Here is the code:

```
//add tracking number for UPS into confirmation page
add_action ('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'acf_trackingnumberups', 20);


    function acf_trackingnumberups( $order ) {

    if (get_field('trackingnumberups', $order->get_id())) { // Only show if field is filled

?>
        <h3>Your tracking number: <strong><?php the_field('trackingnumberups', $order->get_id()); ?></strong></h3>
        <p>You may track your order with the number above, here: <a style="color: #0073aa;" href="https://www.ups.com/tracking/tracking.html">UPS Tracking</a> </p>         
        <?php 

    }

}
```

We have a problem with the flow.

I want to be able to 1) add the tracking code, 2) set the order to complete and 3) update.

Now I have to 1) add the tracking code, 2) update, 3) set the order to complete and 4) update again.

Else, the custom field will not be fetched in the order completion email.

I tried to remove this line:

```
if (get_field('trackingnumberups', $order->get_id())) { // Only show if field is filled
```

It worked but it include the tracking code on all notifications.

I've landed on a plugin that add a save button to a custom field and run an Ajax calls.

Is there a way I can save the page using Ajax ?

Here is the plugin: https://github.com/SnakeO/acf-admin-button-field

Answer (score 0):

I found [the solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356373/)

I forgot to save the values registered from the custom field before adding the information to the order email. No need to add an Ajax button under the field. Also, the plugin is no longer supported.

```
    // save input from metabox
add_action( 'save_post', 'bdev_save_postnord_data_to_order', 10, 1 );
if ( ! function_exists( 'bdev_save_postnord_data_to_order' ) )
{

    function bdev_save_postnord_data_to_order( $post_id ) {

        if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'postnord_meta_field_nonce' ] ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        $nonce = $_REQUEST[ 'postnord_meta_field_nonce' ];

        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        if ( 'page' == $_POST[ 'post_type' ] ) {

            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        } else {

            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        }
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_postnord_field_data', $_POST[ 'postnord_data_name' ] );
    }
}
```